# How to share Azure function around differents solution?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I am working in an app with different functions apps. Each function APP has it own VS solution and now I have to add Health Check to each Function App. Basically a function like this:

```
   public class HealthFunction
    {
        private readonly HealthCheckService _healthCheckService;

        public HealthFunction(HealthCheckService healthCheck)
        {
            _healthCheckService = healthCheck;
        }

        [FunctionName("health")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Health(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "health")]
            HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Received health request");

            var status = await _healthCheckService.CheckHealthAsync();

            return new OkObjectResult(Enum.GetName(typeof(HealthStatus), status.Status));
        }
    }
```

Is there some way to share this **HealthFunction** in something like nuget package? or something else?

Comment: you can just create a new Function of health check and deploy it and call from any of the function

Comment: @AbhishekBorikar I think the point of health check is to verify if particular function app is healthy, not to check health of the health function app.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, function application is basing on the folder structure and existence of function.json files where function trigger and bindings are defined to create a function within a Function App.

You'd need to prepare a package that besides adding a dll, will also add the function.json to the build output.

I didn't try that, it's not simple but it seems doable.

Following links might help you:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v2%2Ccmd#autogenerated-functionjson
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference#function-code